# How do I replicate NSSet with init in swift

Tags: swift, storekit, nsset

I'm trying to replicate this Objective C line in swift:

```
SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] 
initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:self.productID]];
```

The apple docs read that the swift version is :

```
init(productIdentifiers productIdentifiers: NSSet!)
```

So my attempt is

```
let productID:NSSet = NSSet("somevalue");
let request:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers:init(productID));
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want this code:

```
let productID = NSSet(object: "somevalue");
let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID);
```